# jqGrid ASP.NET Parent Row Selection and Child Edit Issue

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am attempting to use jqGrid ASP.NET for the first time and I'm having an issue with properly using a parent and child grid on my form.

**Scenario:** On my form I have two grids, one a parent that displays product information, and a second child grid that is used for editing a collection of prices for the product in the parent row. When a user clicks the plus sign in a parent row, the OnDataRequesting event is handled and I load the child grid with that product's prices. When the user clicks a price in the child grid, I use ClientSideEvents RowSelect and the server side RowEditing event to perform inline editing.

All of this was fairly trivial to set up and works great. Where I'm having an issue is that I'd like the selected row in the parent grid to act like a context for the rest of the page, i.e. the rest of the page displays information related to the product selected (charts, graphs, etc). For this I set up an event handler for the OnRowSelecting event and then trap the RowKey from the event args. That works great. However... the unintended side effect of setting up that handler is that once a user selects a row in the child grid to edit, the OnRowSelecting event fires in the parent, the page posts back, and when the page reloads the child grid is closed and the attempted edit is thwarted.

What I would like to know is, is there any built in way to handle this sort of scenario either through the client side jqGrid library or the Trirand.Web library? Or will I need to write some custom script to either send the selected parent row asynchronously or possibly trap the expanded child grid and attempt to reopen it once the post back is complete? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd brush off the tumbleweeds here and inject the answer I finally received from Trirand's support. As of the time of this writing, you can't do this. If you handle the OnRowSelecting event, you cannot use an editable child grid as they built it to specifically fire the parent's OnRowSelecting event anytime you select a row in a child grid.